# How can I connect a model instance to a user in django?

Tags: python, django

Im looking to make it so the logged in user that creates a profile is linked to their guestprofile model when they create their profile.

When I create the guest profile while logged in, it successfully creates the guest profile, but in the guest profile admin screen there is no user connected to the guest profile model created. Instead there is a dropdown menu listing all users, which makes the connection process manual. Thanks.

Forms.py

```
class AddProfileForm(forms.ModelForm):
    name = forms.CharField(max_length=50, widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}))
    location = forms.CharField(max_length=100, widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}))
    summary = forms.CharField(max_length=500, widget=forms.Textarea(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}))
    profile_pic = forms.ImageField()
    

class Meta:
    model = GuestProfile
    fields = ('name', 'location', 'summary', 'profile_pic')
```

Models.py

```
class GuestProfile(models.Model):

user = models.ForeignKey(User, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
location = models.CharField(max_length=100)
summary = models.TextField(max_length=350)
profile_pic = models.ImageField(null=True, blank=True, upload_to="images/")


def __str__(self):
    return str(self.user)
```

views.py

```
class AddProfileView(CreateView):

    model = GuestProfile
    form_class = AddProfileForm
    template_name = 'profilemanip/addprofile.html'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('home')

    def get_object(self):
        return self.request.user
```

**Edit: I ended up solving my issue by changing my AddProfileView to the following:**

```
def AddProfileView(request,*args,**kwargs):
form = AddProfileForm(request.POST or None)
if form.is_valid():

    obj = form.save(commit=False)

    obj.user = request.user
    obj.save()

    form = AddProfileForm()

return render(request, "profilemanip/addprofile.html", {"form": form})
```